# Appending DOM element to local dom does not apply styles

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

Within my Polymer (`v1.2.3`) element, I need to dynamically append newly created DOM elements to certain local DOM nodes. The elements I am appending contain a `class="foo"`, where class `foo` has styles scoped within my polymer element.

The problem I am facing is that these styles are not applied to the elements.

The following code will exemplify the issue:

```
  attached: function () {
    var el = document.createElement("span");
    el.textContent = "Woof. Woof. Meow!";
    el.classList.add("foo");

    Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector(".bar").appendChild(el);
  }
```

Here is my template:

```
<dom-module id="my-element">
<template>

<style>
   .foo {
        color: red; 
  }
</style>
<div class="bar"></div>
<div class="baz"><span class="foo">I am not added dynamically!</span></div>

</template>
...
</dom-module>
```

In the above template, the element `.foo` within `.baz` will have styles applied to it but, element `.foo` within `.bar` would not (polymer's class `style-scope` is no applied to it).

**Some additional info:**

- `style-scope` not added to dynamically created elements.
- `Polymer.dom(this.root).appendChild(el)` applies styling but, does not   add it at desired location.
- Calling `updateStyles()` or `Polymer.dom.flush()` explicitly after the element is added, does not resolve the issue.
- Polymer version `1.2.2` also contains this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [open bug](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2701) that requires to append `:host:: content` as a prefix to each style.